# Why can't I pass a list comprehension to Django RelatedManager add()?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Given:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    rengo_black_team = models.ManyToManyField(Player)

class OpenChallenge(CommonChallenge):
    rengo_black_team = models.ManyToManyField(Player)
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This `OpenChallenge` method code works:

```
for p in self.rengo_black_team.all():
    self.game.rengo_black_team.add(p)
```

But this code does not:

```
    self.game.rengo_black_team.add([x for x in self.rengo_black_team.all()])
```

Based on the last example [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#saving-foreignkey-and-manytomanyfield-fields) ,

```
>>> john = Author.objects.create(name="John")
>>> paul = Author.objects.create(name="Paul")
>>> george = Author.objects.create(name="George")
>>> ringo = Author.objects.create(name="Ringo")
>>> entry.authors.add(john, paul, george, ringo)
```

it seems like my example should work, but I get

"Field 'id' expected a number but got [<Player: anoek>]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to unpack the list, since `add` expects the objects to be passed as positional arguments and not as a list, so:

```
self.game.rengo_black_team.add(*[x for x in self.rengo_black_team.all()])
```

or just:

```
self.game.rengo_black_team.add(*self.rengo_black_team.all())
```